# c sharp tooltip not working in groupbox

Tags: c#, tooltip, groupbox

I have a pictureBox that has an image of a question mark. I have a tooltip tool added to my form.  If I have the pictureBox on the main form area and set the Tooltip on the pictureBox to "test test" it shows up fine when i hover over it.  If I then move the pictureBox control inside a groupbox control I have, then the tooltip hover stops working and doesn't display anything.  Is it just not possible due to it being in the groupbox? I looked for a method to reference the pictureBox while it is in the groupbox but i shouldn't have to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I was setting my groupbox to disabled.